# Pandas ExcelWriter overwriting sheets using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter, pandas.excelwriter

I have a nested for loop that is taking data from a master file with multiple sheets and splits the data out by user for each sheet. I want to then write each users data to their own file with the same sheets as the master file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
tm_sheet_to_df_map = pd.read_excel(src_file_tm, sheet_name=None)

for key, value in sorted(tm_sheet_to_df_map.items(),reverse=True):           
    tm_group = value.groupby('TM')
    for TM, group_df in tm_group:
        attachment = attachment_path_tm / f'{TM}' / f'Q221 New Accounts - {TM}.xlsx'
        attachment1 = os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(attachment), exist_ok=True)
        writer = ExcelWriter(attachment, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
        group_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name =f'{key}', index=False)
        writer.save()
```

**PROBLEM -** The above script creates a new file for each user, but will only write the final dataframe to each file, instead of adding all sheets from the master file. Any ideas how to write each sheet to the individual files? I've tried moving
writer.save() outside the loop with no luck.

Comment: `group_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name =f'{key}', index=False)
        writer.save()` is executed in each loop, you propably only want to execute that at the end, so place it at the end outside of the loops

Comment: I tried your suggestion by moving those items to the end and outside of the loops. However, there is no data in the Excel files. They are blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an "append" mode for ExcelWriter:

```py
try:
    # append mode will fail if file does not exist
    writer = ExcelWriter(attachment, engine = 'openpyxl', mode="a")
except FileNotFoundError:
    writer = ExcelWriter(attachment, engine = 'openpyxl')
```

[ExcelWriter docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)

Comment: ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!

Comment: You can try an another engine, for example `openpyxl`.

Comment: I tried openpyxl but received the following error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You may need the first spreadsheet opened in `w` mode.

Comment: I meant that the file must exist before you open it in append mode.

Comment: The second option is to create a spreadsheet per user and keep them opened until you write all the things.

Comment: When I use xlsxwriter as the engine, the files get created and exist. The problem is it only writes the last dataframe in the loop to the file.

Comment: The problem is that when you write to a new sheet, you are overwriting the entire file.

Comment: Agreed - that is what I am asking help with based on what I have so far.

Comment: @Mark, updated my answer, now it should work as expected